# Agregar CORS a servicio SOAP con Ionic

Tags: java, ionic, soap, servicio, cors

es para hacer una consulta. Tengo un servicio SOAP al cual necesito implementarle CORS para posteriormente consumir este servicio desde una app movil en Ionic, pero no se por donde comenzar o como hacerlo correctamente.
Se que la implementación de estos en mi Servicio se hacen en el archivo web.xml pero no se por donde comenzar y lo mismo en mi app de Ionic.
Algún consejo o como podría empezar?

[image: servicio soap]

[image: app ionic]

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y no en un problema en concreto, por lo que te invito a que realices el [recorrido o tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)
de la comunidad por si no lo has hecho. El motivo principal de la comunidad es ayudar a solucionar ciertos problemas que puedan surgir en
el camino de un programador, por lo que tu pregunta es muy general como para ser considerada una pregunta que termine en una respuesta
válida y por último lee sobre[¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Creo que esto es u nproblema concreto, solucionar el problema que tiene con CORS. Si te sirve, yo tuve el mismo problema, aquí tienes mi pregunta con la respuesta que me sirvió. Como te ha comentado @jecorrales, si lo pruebas desde un dispositivo físico o un emulador de Android Studio no tendrás que implementarlo, sólo si lo pruebas desde el navegador.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que implementes nada de CORS sobre el servicio web pues Ionic no hace tal validación al ejecutar el código en un dispositivo móvil. Ahora, seguramente tú desarrollo lo harás mayormente probando desde un navegador y no desde el móvil razón por la cual seguramente SI te fallará el consumo del servicio por el tema del CORS, te recomiendo buscar algún plugin para el navegador que te permita saltar la validación CORS y enfocarte en tu desarrollo y no en el tema del CORS

Comment: Tienes alguna pagina o documentación que me pueda ayudar con el consumo del servicio desde ionic  ?